# Create 2 second audio files while recording with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder

i am using `AVAudioRecorder` to record the iphone input. i need to create a file from the recored every 2 seconds (while recording) without damaging the main file i am recording.

Example:

lets say i am recording a 10 secondes file

```
------------------
    10 Seconds
```

during the recording i need to create 2 seconds "chunks" ready to be sent over POST request.

```
--  --  --  --  --
 2   2   2   2   2
```

any head start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to manage this i found out that i must use apple's `Audio Queue Services` which is a c based API. here is a [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AboutAudioQueues/AboutAudioQueues.html)

this stuff is really cool!

Comment: We're you ever able to complete this? If so, it would be awesome if you could share the code!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to break the audio file into 2-second chunks for sending over a POST request? Can't you send out the data using multipart form data?

Try using an API like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to send out the audio file over the request.